# Como Remover uma imagem que está destacada dentro do post

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Tudo bem?

Preciso de uma ajuda, possuo o seguinte site https://www.tibiatravel.com... é um Fã Site de jogo que estou montando.

Meu problema, para que fique tudo organizado e direitinho na pagina inicial eu preciso adicionar uma imagem de destaque no wordpress para cada post só que quando entro no post a imagem de destaque está lá no inicio de tudo. Minha pergunta é, onde removo essa imagem dentro do post para que ele não poste mais?

https://www.tibiatravel.com/01/04/2020/a-chylling-experience/ Segue link do post como exemplo.

Wordpress 5.4
Tema Usado - Purea Magazine by Spiracle Themes

Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 0):

Você vai ter que editar o TEMA, ou criar um tema FILHO e editar o lugar onqe que, esse posicionamento é definido no tema.